# Search by row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an hdf file which is printed out like this:

```
print dt['data1']
=>

              column1  column2  column3  
row1                3        8        2        
row2                4        3        0  
row3                12       1        14
row4                -5       5        25
```

1) How can I search by rows or rather "select" it? That is,

```
dt.get_row('row3')
=> row3                12       1        14
```

2) And how can I search by row and column value? That is

```
dt.get_row('row2').where(column_value=3)
=> column2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting your the pandas `DataFrame` to `df`:

```
df = dt['data1']
```

You can get the row with `ix`:

```
 df.ix['row3']
```

This gives the result as a `Series`:

```
column1    12
column2     1
column3    14
Name: row3, dtype: int64
```

You can also access the values as NumPy a array:

```
>>> df.ix['row3'].values
array([12,  1, 14])
```

or the name of the row:

```
>>> df.ix['row3'].name
'row3'
```

and the column in `row2` where the value is equal to `3` with:

```
r2 = df.ix['row2']
r2[r2.eq(3)].index
```

This gives you an `Index` object:

```
Index(['column2'], dtype='object')
```

You can access single elements too:

```
>>> r2[r2.eq(3)].index[0]
'column2'
```

Comment: `df.ix['row3']` --> how can I find `column` (its name) which has a value, say, `12`?

Comment: The solution is in the second part of my answer:   `r3 = df.ix['row3']` than
`r3[r3.eq(12)].index` for all column names or `r3[r3.eq(12)].index[0]` for the first if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that I could get working. Not sure if it is the best way to do it.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7], 'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]})
>>> df
    AAA  BBB  CCC<br>
0    4   10  100<br>
1    5   20   50<br>
2    6   30  -30<br>
3    7   40  -50<br>
>>> df.iloc[0]
AAA      4
BBB     10
CCC    100
Name: 0, dtype: int64
>>> df.iloc[0].AAA
4
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.